# I wish to run test cases based on the run mode declared in an excel

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Please find the below codes and the query mentioned at the last.

****Annotation List****

```
public interface AnnotationList{

@Documented

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

public @interface QCID {


   String[] value();

}

@Documented

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

public @interface Author {


    String value();

}

@Documented

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface Order {


    int value();

}


@Documented

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface MyTest {


    static class None extends Throwable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private None() {


       }}
```

**JUnitLink**

```
public class JunitLink extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {


// TODO work in test status to see if things should be run.


public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JunitLink.class);


public JunitLink(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {

    super(klass);
  }


@Override

public void run(final RunNotifier notifier) {

    JunitLink.super.run(notifier);
}



    @Override

protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {

List<FrameworkMethod> classMethods = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(AnnotationList.MyTest.class);

SortedMap<Integer, FrameworkMethod> sortedTestMethodList = new TreeMap<Integer,FrameworkMethod>();

    for (FrameworkMethod seleniumTest : classMethods) {

        if (seleniumTest.getAnnotation(AnnotationList.Order.class) != null) {

        sortedTestMethodList.put(seleniumTest.getAnnotation(AnnotationList.Order.class).value(),seleniumTest);

        }

    }

    return new ArrayList<FrameworkMethod>(sortedTestMethodList.values());

}


@Override

protected void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {

    EachTestNotifier eachNotifier = makeNotifier(method, notifier);

if (method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) != null) {

        runIgnored(eachNotifier);

    } else {

        runNotIgnored(method, eachNotifier);

}

    logger.info("Test {} run completed", method.getName());
}


private int runNotIgnored(FrameworkMethod method,EachTestNotifier eachNotifier) {

    int failures = 0;

    eachNotifier.fireTestStarted();

try {

        methodBlock(method).evaluate();

} 
catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {

        eachNotifier.addFailedAssumption(e);

        logger.error("Test {} failed!", method.getName());

        failures++;
    } 
catch (Throwable e) {

        eachNotifier.addFailure(e);

        logger.error("Test {} failed!", method.getName());

        failures++;

} finally {

        eachNotifier.fireTestFinished();

    }

    return failures;

}


    private void runIgnored(EachTestNotifier eachNotifier) {


    eachNotifier.fireTestIgnored();

}


    private EachTestNotifier makeNotifier(FrameworkMethod method,RunNotifier notifier) {

    Description description = describeChild(method);


return new EachTestNotifier(notifier, description);

}}
```

**Start Up Test**

```
@RunWith(JunitLink.class)

public class StartUp extends SeleneseTestBase {

public static readProperties settings = new readProperties();

public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(INF.class);
public static WebDriver driver;


public static Actions actions;




@Override

@Before
public void setUp()
{

}


@Override

@After
public void tearDown() {

}


@BeforeClass

public static void StartBrowser() {

    //Start Driver etc

}


@AfterClass

public static void tearClassDown() {

    //Kill driver

}
}
```

//**Test Cases Are Written Like These**

```
@Author("XXXX")


@QCID({ "Smoke_TC01", "Smoke_TC02", "Smoke_TC03",
    "TC04"})

public class SmokeTest extends Startup{

private Components component = new Components();
private String TestDataSheetName = "Smoke";

public SmokeTest() throws Exception {

}

@MyTest
@Order(1)
public void openHomepage() throws Exception {
    component.openAPP();
}

@MyTest
@Order(2)
public void Login() throws Exception {
    component.Login(USID, PWD);

}

@MyTest
@Order(3)
public void isTerminalLocked() throws Exception {
    component.isTerminalLocked();
}
```

All the test method runs in order. Now I want to run only specific test cases which have runmode as "Yes" declared in a excel. I can add extraline before each test cases to read the lines from excel and run the particular test case but I want to read the excel and pass the selected testcases(based on runmode) to Junit runner.

Please help me.

Comment: I have many test cases like SmokeTest.class file ( Given as an example above) in the test suite package.

Comment: So you are looking to conditionally disable tests, based on data in an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is borderline "too broad". It's possible it may get closed for this reason.

Have a look at [A JUnit Rule to Conditionally Ignore Tests](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/). From that your `isSatisfied()` will have to parse your Excel. You can use something like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So for each class I have run the isSatisfied method to check the Runmode. i am actually doing this currently using jxl. But i wanted to get all the runnable test case list at a go and invoke them rather than checking for each time. I have over 900 TC and each tcs(scenarios) i have several methods(steps).

Comment: Read the Excel once into an array or something, and then each TC will only check this array. Please note: this is definitely getting into a discussion now, rather than Q&A style, which is the preferred format for SO. See [Ask].